# Process text entered and then show the updated state in TextInput in react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to process the new character inputted in `TextInput` field, update the state, and then show the updated state in the `TextInput` using Value. I am able to do so but the text kind of **flickers** every time I update it.

In my opinion, this is due to the time it takes to process and then render it again.
Is there a way around to stop this from happening as this is turning out to be a bad user experience?

Edit:

1. What I am trying to achieve :-

   ```
    const [input, setInput] = useState("")

    const inputHandler = async(text) => {
    let check = await isRTL();

    if(check)
        text = text.substring(text.length-1,text.length) + text.substring(0,text.length-1);

        setInput(text);
    }

    return (
    <TextInput value = {input} onChangeText={inputHandler} {...props} style = {{...props.style, textAlign: myDirection().start}} >
        {props.children}
    </TextInput>
    )
   ```

Comment: @nima Yes I tried that already and it wasn't working. Tried it both on AVD and my personal android mobile too

Comment: @nima yes that problem persists

Comment: @nima I wasn't home, that's why could not check .Thank you for the suggestions but I'll have to pass the props as there might be more stuff than value, onChangeText and style which could be used. As for I18nManager I already checked that and the flickering problem still exists. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: @nima Thanks for helping but I am unable to understand as to how to remove the use of repeating props because if I do not use {...props} then some of the functionalities that  I want to use in the custom tag will be lost and if I do not include {...props.style, } then I would not be able to set the custom style that I want to use for RTL. And the main problem is still the flickering inside the text input which is not being rectified even if I remove one of the props use